# FOR LOOP - in need some valiable assistance

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf

I need a web page generating a PDF file that returns multiple values for the same row in a sql db table. Right now it is working as it is getting the results I need, but only for table row number 1. But I have 1600+ rows and I would like to have the pdf with all rows.. (A4 pdf, with 2 results per page)

**Code**

```
<?php

require_once('include/menu.php');
include_once("mfpdf/mpdf.php");
include_once('include/ez_sql.inc');

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'pt_PT');
$socio = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM socios where estado = 'ACTIVO'");

$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',32,25,27,25,16,13);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;

$mpdf -> allow_charset_conversion=true;
$mpdf->charset_in='utf-8';

// $stylesheet = file_get_contents('mfpdf/mpdfstyletables.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);    // *** The parameter 1 tells that this    is css/style only and no body/html/text
$cont = 0;

foreach ($socio as $socio1) {

$cont = $cont + 1;
$ano = date("Y");
$idade = age(dtPadrao($socio->nascimento));
if ($idade >= 18) $Vquota = 1.50;
else $Vquota = 1;

$Vquota = money_format('%.2n', $Vquota);

$html = '
<br /><br />
<table width="794px" height="462px" align="center" style="border: 0px solid #880000; background-color: #FFF; " class="tallcells">
    <tr>
        <td height="462px" width="250px" valign="top" align="left">
            <br><br><img src="img/sfal_logo.png" height="140px"><br><br><br>
            <table border="2px" align="center">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left"><font size="5"><h3>SOCIO N&ordm; '.$socio1->n_socio.'</h3><br />
                            '.$socio1->nome.'<br />
                            '.$socio1->morada.'<br />
                            '.$socio1->cod_postal.' - '.$socio1->localidade.'<br />
                            <br />Ano '.$ano.'<br />
                            Valor Mensal: '.$Vquota.'
                            <br /><br />
                            Local de Cobran&ccedil;a:<br />
                            '.$socio1->local_cobranca.'</font><br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td width="544px">                      <!-- was 10px  10px-->
            <table cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="15px" align="center">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #880000; background-color: #FFF;" width="190px" class="tallcells" align="center"><font size="5">
                        SFAL
                        <br />S&oacute;cio n.: '.$socio1->n_socio.'
                        <br />Valor:  '.$Vquota.'
                        <br />DEZEMBRO
                        <br />'.$ano.'</font></td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #880000; background-color: #FFF; " width="190px" class="tallcells" align="center"><font size="5">
                        SFAL
                        <br />S&oacute;cio n.: '.$socio1->n_socio.'
                        <br />Valor:  '.$Vquota.'
                        <br />NOVEMBRO
                        <br />'.$ano.'</font></td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #880000; background-color: #FFF; " width="190px" class="tallcells" align="center"><font size="5">
                        SFAL
                        <br />S&oacute;cio n.: '.$socio1->n_socio.'
                        <br />Valor:  '.$Vquota.'
                        <br />OUTUBRO
                        <br />'.$ano.'</font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #880000; background-color: #FFF; " class="tallcells" align="center"><font size="5">
                        SFAL
                        <br />S&oacute;cio n.: '.$socio1->n_socio.'
                        <br />Valor:  '.$Vquota.'
                        <br />SETEMBRO
                        <br />'.$ano.'</font></td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #880000; background-color: #FFF; " class="tallcells" align="center"><font size="5">
                        SFAL
                        <br />S&oacute;cio n.: '.$socio1->n_socio.'
                        <br />Valor:  '.$Vquota.'
                        <br />AGOSTO
                        <br />'.$ano.'</font></td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #880000; background-color: #FFF; " class="tallcells" align="center"><font size="5">
                        SFAL
                        <br />S&oacute;cio n.: '.$socio1->n_socio.'
                        <br />Valor:  '.$Vquota.'
                        <br />JULHO
                        <br />'.$ano.'</font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #880000; background-color: #FFF; " class="tallcells" align="center"><font size="5">
                        SFAL
                        <br />S&oacute;cio n.: '.$socio1->n_socio.'
                        <br />Valor:  '.$Vquota.'
                        <br />JUNHO
                        <br />'.$ano.'</font></td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #880000; background-color: #FFF; " class="tallcells" align="center"><font size="5">
                        SFAL
                        <br />S&oacute;cio n.: '.$socio1->n_socio.'
                        <br />Valor:  '.$Vquota.'
                        <br />MAIO
                        <br />'.$ano.'</font></td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #880000; background-color: #FFF; " class="tallcells" align="center"><font size="5">
                        SFAL
                        <br />S&oacute;cio n.: '.$socio1->n_socio.'
                        <br />Valor:  '.$Vquota.'
                        <br />ABRIL
                        <br />'.$ano.'</font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #880000; background-color: #FFF; " class="tallcells" align="center"><font size="5">
                        SFAL
                        <br />S&oacute;cio n.: '.$socio1->n_socio.'
                        <br />Valor:  '.$Vquota.'
                        <br />MAR&Ccedil;O
                        <br />'.$ano.'</font></td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #880000; background-color: #FFF; " class="tallcells" align="center"><font size="5">
                        SFAL
                        <br />S&oacute;cio n.: '.$socio1->n_socio.'
                        <br />Valor:  '.$Vquota.'
                        <br />FEVEREIRO
                        <br />'.$ano.'</font></td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #880000; background-color: #FFF; " class="tallcells" align="center"><font size="5">
                        SFAL
                        <br />S&oacute;cio n.: '.$socio1->n_socio.'
                        <br />Valor:  '.$Vquota.'
                        <br />JANEIRO
                        <br />'.$ano.'</font></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br /><br /><br />
';

//==============================================================
//==============================================================
//==============================================================



// $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');


$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
if ($cont == 50) break;

//==============================================================
//==============================================================
//==============================================================

}
$mpdf->Output('mpdf.pdf','I');
exit;
?>
```

Comment: your db interface looks like it;s pulling only a single row: `$db->get_row`. anyone can tell you how to implement a loop but without seeing your DB class we have no way of knowing how you can pull all the records from the db instead of a single row.

Comment: my db class? sorry but.. what do you mean?!

Comment: i mean the file: `ez_sql.inc` which handles your database interactions. i looked it up on github but as of right now github is offline.

Comment: this db is like a club associate list, with associate number (n_socio) name, adress, phone number... etc.. so, I ws trying to get the html to repeat and for each time it did, it would go to the db and get the following associate.. 1, 2, 3... 1600!

Comment: alright well i'm sorry you're not understanding what i'm saying but the bottom line is, unless someone else comes along who is already familiar with the library you're using it will be hard to get an answer from someone while github is down.

Comment: ok, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

based on the doc found here : https://ezsql.github.io/ezSQL/ez_sql_help.htm 
the method `$db->get_row()` retreives only one row from the database. to get all the rows, you need to use `$db->get_results()` instead

Then, you have to loop on the results using a foreach loop as shown on the example from the doc :

```
$users = $db->get_results("SELECT name, email FROM users");

foreach ( $users as $user )
{
            // Access data using object syntax
            echo $user->name;
            echo $user->email;
}
```

Comment: CROZET that actually kind of worked.. I did as you sugested, and now my outcome is the data on all fields of the last row.. for some reason it's not repeating the code.

Comment: @RuiNeves ok that is a progress, can you add the updated code in your question ?

Comment: C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ I cant put all the code here because it is too long for a comment but here's what I changed:    
$socio = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM socios");            
foreach ($socio as $socio1) {                                                                                      and I am now calling the db info with $socio1

Comment: Just edit your original question to put the full code. It seems that the part you put in the comment is correct but without the full code, it will be hard to tell where is the mistake

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!

went with CROZET's sugestion and added a $count var to ease the html repetion.

thank you.